# Script creation of a video from images while specifying how long to show each image?

Tags: video, script

There seem to be several ways to convert images to videos, but they all appear to just let you show each video a fixed amount of time. Does anybody know of a way to script the creation of a video from image files that lets you specify the length to show each image?

E.g.

```
magicSoftware.exe out=video.mp4 | in=file1.png time=100ms | in=file2.png time=400ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any tool that can do this as a simple one-off command; you could, however, convert your images individually to videos (of varying length) and then concatenate those videos together - I would use ffmpeg for this.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i input1.png -t 6 -crf 22 -preset veryfast 01.ts
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i input2.png -t 9 -crf 22 -preset veryfast 02.ts
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i input3.png -t 4 -crf 22 -preset veryfast 03.ts
```

`-t` sets the output duration in seconds. You can also use fractions of seconds, so `-t 2.2` will give you a duration of 2.2 seconds. If you wish to specify length in terms of video frames, you can use `-vframes` of `frames:v`; by default, this command will give you 25frames per second. Then, concatenate the MPEG TS files together into a single MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:01.ts|02.ts|03.ts" -c copy output.mp4
```

Of course, it would be possible to script this (I know how I'd do it in bash, but I don't have any knowledge of scripting on Windows).